# Jquery Cookie plugin - multiple values from data- attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I want to add multiple values to a $.cookie plugin from a data attribute. I have a list of hotels on a page and when clicked a link with a data attribute data-hotel-id I want to add the value of hotel-id to a cookie. The problem is when I want to add more values. My code:

```
$('a.js-hotel-box').click(function( event ){
        event.preventDefault();
        obj =  $(this);                      
        hotelId = obj.data("hotel-id");

        $.cookie("hotel-comparison", hotelId , { path: '/' });
});
```

The problem is that it always overwrite the cookie value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to check if the `$.cookie("hotel-comparison")` exists

```
$('a.js-hotel-box').click(function( event ){
        event.preventDefault();
        var obj =  $(this),                      
            hotelId = obj.data("hotel-id");
            ids = $.cookie("hotel-comparison")

         if(!ids)
          $.cookie("hotel-comparison", hotelId , { path: '/' });
         else
          $.cookie("hotel-comparison", ids + "," + hotelId , { path: '/' }); 
});
```